# PHP require warning says "no such file" even though the warning traces out the correct file path

Tags: php, require-once

I am trying to require a file in a different folder, but php keeps saying the file does not exist.

"Warning: require_once(./include/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\include\members.php on line 2"

Other pages have been able to access this file without issue, but when it's in the scripts folder instead of the home folder or the include folder, it says the file does not exist. The path that is output in this error is correct, so why is it failing?

Comment: `.` indicates that you trying to get file in the same folder try use such `require_once(../include/config.php)`

Comment: But why would that `config.php` include itself anyhow? Use `DOCUMENT_ROOT`-referencing paths.

Comment: I've tried with ../ instead of ./ but it gives the same error regardless.

Comment: Is the include directory in the document root? If so, use `/include/config.php`

Answer (score 0):

if you need to back use `../`

For example: `require_once("../include/config.php")`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the problem. The issue was actually an require within the file I was trying to include. I guess since the required file was being called outside of its folder, I had to include the full file path for the file that the required file was requiring.

This might be a sign that I have too much spaghetti-code... Thanks for all the help though. :)